# Failed to load csb file in xcode

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, libpng

I have a game source code which previously has been submitted to app store. for now i am going to resubmit it with better performance but have been faced weird issue. there are already .csb files for each scene in the source code. i have googled and understood how i have to use cocos studio 2.0. for testing purpose i opened old cocos studio project file (.css) and republished it with no changes. and then copy from res folder and paste it into resource folder. but when the xcode tried to load .csb file it crashed.

```
mainLayer = (Layer*)CSLoader::createNode("GameScene.csb");
```

the source code works fine with old .csb file. but not worked with new one.

xcode gave me no correct reason. I can see only some setting values in debugger view like this.

- when i tried with new .csb which i've republished

> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
>
> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
>
> suffix = csb
>
> textureSize = 7

no more

- when i tried with old .csb from old source code

> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
>
> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
>
> suffix = csb
>
> textureSize = 0

many more...

as you can see, with new one, the app crashed after printed textureSize.

i am using cocos2dx v3.3 and cocos studio v2.2.1
could you please explain about how should i avoid this issue?

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Libpng-1.6 is stricter than older versions about bad ICC sRGB profiles.
There is a new C function that you can call to skip the sRGB profile checking:

```
png_set_option(png_ptr, PNG_SKIP_sRGB_CHECK_PROFILE, PNG_OPTION_ON);
```

If you're not using C you'll need to find out the equivalent way of doing that.

They are just warnings.  A more permanent, and better, solution if you own the image files is to fix the PNG files by removing the bad ICC profiles, which are contained in the PNG iCCP chunk, using your favorite PNG editor.

Having an sRGB profile in an iCCP chunk is just bloat anyway, because applications will assume the image is in the sRGB colorspace if there's no ICC profile present.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with libpng warning.

This problem may be because some versions of cocos2d-x and cocostudio are not compatible to each other
Update both cocostudio and cocos2d-x to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the in AppDelegate.cpp the addSearchPath, for example

if you have the .csb files in Resource/cocosstudio add this on applicationDidFinishLaunching() function :

```
FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchPath("cocosstudio");
```

In my proyect i call it like this:

```
auto node = CSLoader::createNode("MainScene.csb");
```